# Proof that if $a \mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = d$ then $a/d$ divides $c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that if $a \mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = d$ then $a/d$ divides $c$.

#### Attempt at solution

\begin{align}
&a \mid bc \implies \exists \ x \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{s.t} \quad  bc = ax \tag{1}\\
&\gcd(a,b) = d \implies a \mid b \implies \exists \ t \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{s.t} \quad b = at\tag{2} \\
&\gcd(a,b) = d \implies a \mid d \implies \exists \ s \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{s.t} \quad d = as\tag{3} 
\end{align}
From $(2)$ , we get $a = b/t$. Substituting in $(3)$, we have $d = as = bs/t  \implies b = dt/s$. Substituting this last result in $(1)$ ;
$$ bc = ax \implies \frac{dt}{s} c = ax.$$
Since $t,s$ and $x$ are all arbitrary constants in $\mathbb{Z}$, define $sx/t := x^{\prime} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Finally,
$$ dc = ax^{\prime}\implies c= \frac{a}{d}x' \implies \frac{a}{d} \mid c  \qquad \square.$$

Can anyone confirm my proof ? I feel like there are some justifications missing. Particularly in the substitions part could there not be divisions by $0$?

Comment: Why would $gcd(a,b)=d$ imply $a | b$?

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 Right, thank you for pointing that out !

Answer (score 1):

$$a \text{ divides }bc \quad\Longrightarrow \quad\frac{a}{d} \text{ divides }  \frac{b}{d}  c \quad\Longrightarrow \quad\frac{a}{d} \text{ divides }  c$$

the last implication being true because $a/d$ and $b/d$ are coprime.

Comment: Interesting, but why is the first implication true ?

Comment: Because $bc=ax$ gives $(b/d)c=(a/d)x$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.